# pafy Runtime warning "youtube-dl not found "

Tags: youtube-dl, pafy

I recently installed `pafy` for `windows` and getting following message during runtime.

> Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
>   Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >
> > > WARNING:root:pafy: youtube-dl not found; falling back to internal backend. This is not as well maintained as the youtube-dl backend. To hide this message, set the environmental variable PAFY_BACKEND to "internal".

How do I setup environmental variable for `PAFY_BACKEND` and get rid of Warning?

Answer (score 5):

Youtube-dl is a separate module from pafy. Instead of hiding the warning, you'll save yourself trouble if you go ahead and download it. Go to command module and run this exactly:

`pip install youtube-dl`.

That should install youtube-dl to the same directory as pafy, and the warning should disappear.

Comment: In Ubuntu's Python3 interpreter, `import pafy` returns a similar error, because `youtube-dl` is not included as a dependency with the `python3-pafy` installation from the Ubuntu/Debian repo. After I installed `youtube-dl` in Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla 20.10 (dev), that error msg goes away.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows type this command in your command line: `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl .

Else if you are using Mac or unix, follow the this link `[youtube-dl installation on unix and Mac OS x](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)

This is to install youtube-dl on your machine after which the warning will no longer appear.